# Haml - get current week start and end date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm new into HAML, and I have ( I hope easy ) question regarding date/ time. Is it possible to get start and end date of current week in HAML in not very very commplicated way? I want to use those dates for navigation in my calendar.

For month and year is rather easy:

```
- year       = Date.today.year
- month      = Date.today.month
- day        = Date.today
- monthEnd   = year.to_s + "-" + month.to_s + "-" + Integer(Date.new(year, month, -1).strftime("%d")).to_s
- monthStart = Date.new(year, month, 1)
- yearStart  = year.to_s + "-01-01";
- yearEnd    = year.to_s + "-12-31";
```

If it is not possible, I will do it in Javascript, but I would like to have this consistent.

Comment: are you also using rails?

Comment: Yes, I've just updated tag list

Comment: Ok, I'm done with editing my answer, it should be understandable by now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, these are the methods you're looking for:

```
Date.today.beginning_of_week
Date.today.end_of_week
```

If you want to set the beginning of the week to sunday, you can do so in an initializer. Remember to restart your server.

**initializers/set_beginning_of_week.rb**

```
Date.today.beginning_of_week = :sunday
```

### Further Improvements

The HAML syntax `-` is equivalent to ERB `<% %>`. So this is used for coding Ruby code in your views.

In your views you *should not* set a long list of variables or perform complex functions. You should try to limit these to `if`, `else`, `each` & other basic operations.

Additionally, for these type of functions you can call helper methods.

I'd setup some basic helpers like:

**helpers/application_helper.rb**

```
def current_date
  Date.today # or use Time.zone.today as Rob suggested
end

def current_month
  current_date.month
end

def current_year
  current_date.year
end
```

Resulting in **easy calls**

```
current_year
current_month
current_date

current_date.beginning_of_week
current_date.end_of_week

current_month.beginning_of_month
current_month.end_of_month

current_year.beginning_of_year
current_year.end_of_year
```

This can then be implemented in any view.

**views/foo/show.html.haml**

```
.calendar_header
  - current_year

%p Beginning of month is
  - current_month.beginning_of_month
```

Comment: For Rails apps that follow USA conventions (first day of week is Sunday), you can set the beginning of the week: `Date.beginning_of_week = :sunday`. After setting that attribute, other date expressions like `Time.zone.now.end_of_week` do the Right Thing.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the week starts on Sunday and ends on Saturday, and you want to use Ruby's standard library:

`- weekStart = Date.today.prev_day(Date.today.cwday)`

`- weekEnd   = Date.today.next_day(6-Date.today.cwday)`

BTW, I would probably take advantage of `Time.zone.now` instead of `Date.today` if you're using Rails. Same idea for your other ones. More on that in [this blog](http://winstonyw.com/2014/03/03/time_now_vs_time_zone_now/).

@TheChamp:

Rails has convenience methods for doing just this:

`weekStart = Time.zone.today.beginning_of_week`

`weekEnd   = Time.zone.today.end_of_week`

Comment: why wouldn't you use `beginning_of_week` or `end_of_week`?

Comment: When I posted my original answer he hadn't said he was using Rails so I just wrote a quick way to do it with standard Ruby classes, then completely forgot about these methods when I edited. I will edit now since you're absolutely right.

Comment: Nice, also +1 for the `Time.zone.today`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a HAML issue, it's more a Ruby and/or Rails issue. Have a look at the rails date and time helpers:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html

They allow you to do:

```
week_start = Time.now.beginning_of_week
```

Comment: Any reason for the down vote? My response of using the rails date time helpers is also included in the other two answers.

Comment: Guessing: you provided code for the beginning of the year. OP isn't interested in the beginning of the year.

Comment: From original example: yearStart  = year.to_s + "-01-01";

Comment: OP's question: "Is it possible to get start and end date of current week...?"

Comment: I've fixed that - I look forward to being deluged with up-votes.